# Python Datetime module

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, datetime

My project is too let the user enter their birth date and the computer output the number of days they have been alive, how old they are, how many days until their next birthday and what the weekday was when they were born.

I have managed to do them all but when I get to the amount of days until their next birthday I have to get the user to type in their next birthday - I need it to be so that it uses the original input instead of a new one.

How can I get it so they do not need to input their next birthday?

I've figured out if you add the age of the user to the birthday year it can give you the number of days without inputting your next birthday. But I'm not sure how to add it onto it. I am able to add a number i.e 1 or 14 to the year but not a variable.

```
next_birthday = birthday.replace(year=birthday.year+ 14)

import datetime
from datetime import date

birthday=input("When is your birthday ['yyyy-mm-dd' format] : ")
birthday=datetime.datetime.strptime(birthday,"%Y-%m-%d").date()
today = datetime.date.today()
age = (today - birthday)

print("You are " + str(age.days) + " days old")

days = (age.days)
years = days/365

print("Or " + str(years) + " years old")

weekday = date.weekday(birthday)
days= ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
print ("You were born on the day number %d" % weekday)
print ("Which was a " + days[weekday])


birthdate=input("When is your next Birthday ['yyyy-mm-dd' format] : ")
birthdate=datetime.datetime.strptime(birthdate,"%Y-%m-%d").date()
while birthdate == today:
    print ("Happy Birthday")
    break
else:
    import datetime
    today = datetime.date.today()

    daystill = (birthdate- today).days
    print (daystill, "Days untill your Birthday")
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add 1 to the year:

`birthday = datetime.datetime.strptime('2000-01-01', "%Y-%m-%d").date()`

`next_birthday = birthday.replace(year=age.year+1)`

Comment: if i do this the program just outputs a negative number of days untill the next birthday.

Comment: this will celebrate the 1 year birthday, not the next one